# Linq: Polymophic entity fetch in select list

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4.1

I want to do the following...

```
FROM o IN orders
SELECT new OrderContainer { Contact = (PostalContact) o.Contact  }
```

So hopefully you can see that the order's 'Contact' will be of a derived type. Unfortunately however it doesn't seem to do a polymorphic fetch! Is there anyway of achieving this?

Cheers, Ian.

Comment: Is `PostalContact` mapped entity inherited from `Contact`?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the extention method .OfType()

```
from o in orders 
select new OrderContainer { Contact = o.Contact.OfType<PostalContact>().FirstOrDefault() }
```

Edit:

a way to get the full object data, but i doubt that this is good enough for your needs.

```
from c in contacts.OfType<PostalContact>()
where c.Orders.Any(o=>o.Contact.Id == c.id)    
select new OrderContainer { Contact = c }
```

on the other hand, if you set the base class (entity) to **abstract**, you may find that entity will load the full objects. but this is not recomended due to the queries that are generated. if you are looking into this you may want to look at (**TPH**) Table per Hierarchy for your contacts

Comment: I don't think that's going to work becuase o.Contact is not IEnumnerable.

Comment: I agree, i missed that on my first attempt to answer

Comment: Well thanks for your effort. I'm going to do a lower level query using joins now anyhow.